# Server returns plain list of objects instead of ODATA envelope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, count, asp.net-core-mvc, odata

I have implemented ODATA configuration in my application. Everything seems OK, some ODATA operators like Filter, Select, Top work, but the result is just list of plain of objects, not odata formatted. That is why, some operators like $count does not work.

Here is my `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddOData();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    IEdmModel model = GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices);

    app.UseMvc(route => 
    {
        route.Expand().Select().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

        route.EnableDependencyInjection();
        route.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
        route.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}");
    });
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
    builder.EntitySet<Models.Customer>("Customers");

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Here is my action method in `HomeController` class

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable GetList()
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    return db.Customers;
}
```

Request to `.../odata/Customers` returns 404 not found.

Request to `.../api/Home/GetList?$top=2&$select=id,name&$count=true`
returns this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 748885,
        "Name": "VALERİY ŞAMƏMMƏDOVİÇ ŞİRİNOV"
    },
    {
        "Id": 748886,
        "Name": "VAQİF ƏBÜLFƏT MƏMMƏDOV"
    }
]
```

But the expected result is:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost:60071/odata/$metadata",
  "@odata.count": 123,
  "value": [
    {
        "Id": 748885,
        "Name": "VALERİY ŞAMƏMMƏDOVİÇ ŞİRİNOV"
    },
    {
        "Id": 748886,
        "Name": "VAQİF ƏBÜLFƏT MƏMMƏDOV"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Tamerlan! Did you find the cause of this? I'm in the same situation with newly released OData 7.3 for ASP.nET Core 3.1